# How to animate DropShadow without affecting other Nodes?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I tried to animate a `Node`'s `DropShadow`, but it seems affecting other nodes (and/or instances of the same node) that has a dropshadow effect within the scene graph. I'm currently using this approach for the animation:

```
DropShadow shadow = (DropShadow) node.getEffect();
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().setAll(
  new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
    new KeyValue(shadow.radiusProperty(), shadow.getRadius()),
    new KeyValue(shadow.spreadProperty(), shadow.getSpread()),
    new KeyValue(shadow.offsetXProperty(), shadow.getOffsetX()),
    new KeyValue(shadow.offsetYProperty(), shadow.getOffsetY())
  ),
  new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
    new KeyValue(shadow.radiusProperty(), NEW_DROP_SHADOW.getRadius()),
    new KeyValue(shadow.spreadProperty(), NEW_DROP_SHADOW.getSpread()),
    new KeyValue(shadow.offsetXProperty(), NEW_DROP_SHADOW.getOffsetX()),
    new KeyValue(shadow.offsetYProperty(), NEW_DROP_SHADOW.getOffsetY())
  )
);
```

What was the proper way to animate a shadow effect in JavaFX?

Comment: Do you apply the same effect instance for all those nodes?

Comment: @fabian Yes, because I have a class with static dropshadow variables for convenient setting of node's effect. Maybe that is the problem? Wait... I'll test my code and see if that is the case...

Comment: @fabian OMG! Thank you for pointing that out. I'll fix my code now. Thank you very much!